# Pyspark - Create a json column whose keys are from another CSV column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The input dataset looks like this

```
 |    id     | fields     | f1       | f2         | f3       | f4         |
 | --------  | --------   | -------- | --------   | -------- | --------   |
 |     1     | f1, f2, f3 | 3        |  2         |     0    |     2      |
 |     2     | f2, f4     | 2        |  4         |     2    |     5      |
 |     3     | f1         | 7        |  6         |     4    |     6      |
```

The expected output is

```
 |    id     | fields     | json_field                      |
 | --------  | --------   | ------------------------------- |    
 |     1     | f1, f2, f3 | {"f1": 3, "f2": 2, "f3": 0}     |     
 |     2     | f2, f4     | {"f2": 4, "f4": 5}              |     
 |     3     | f1         | {"f1": 7}                       |
```

I have tried

```
    input_df.selet(
        col("id"),
        col("fields"),
        to_json(struct(split(col("fields"), ","))).alias("json_field")
    )
```

But it does not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a straightforward solution. Follow these steps:

- Transform the `columns` into the `map<string, string>` type by using `from_json(to_json(struct(*)), 'map<string, string>')`.
- Split the `fields` and retrieve each field, then search for it in the `map<string, string>`.

```
df
.withColumn("keys", expr("from_json(to_json(struct(*)), 'map<string, string>')"))
.selectExpr(
   "id",
   "fields",
   "transform(split(fields, ','), field -> keys[field]) AS json_fields"
)
.show(false)
```

```
+---+--------+-----------+
|id |fields  |json_fields|
+---+--------+-----------+
|1  |f1,f2,f3|[3, 2, 0]  |
|2  |f2,f4   |[4, 5]     |
|3  |f1      |[7]        |
+---+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `collect_list` and `map_from_entries` on the `struct` Spark SQL functions to create the map dynamically based on the `fields` column:

```py
data = [(1, "f1, f2, f3", 3, 2, 0, 2),
        (2, "f2, f4", 2, 4, 2, 5),
        (3, "f1", 7, 6, 4, 6)]
input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "fields", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"])

input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_view")
// INPUT: input_view
// +---+----------+---+---+---+---+
// |id |fields    |f1 |f2 |f3 |f4 |
// +---+----------+---+---+---+---+
// |1  |f1, f2, f3|3  |2  |0  |2  |
// |2  |f2, f4    |2  |4  |2  |5  |
// |3  |f1        |7  |6  |4  |6  |
// +---+----------+---+---+---+---+

output_df = spark.sql(
  """
    |WITH exploded_view AS (
    |  SELECT id, explode(split(fields, ', ')) as field, f1, f2, f3, f4
    |  FROM input_view
    |  )
    |SELECT
    | id,
    | collect_list(field) as fields,
    | map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(field, CASE field WHEN 'f1' THEN f1 WHEN 'f2' THEN f2 WHEN 'f3' THEN f3 WHEN 'f4' THEN f4 END))) as json_field
    | FROM exploded_view
    | GROUP BY id, f1, f2, f3, f4
    | ORDER BY id
    |""".stripMargin)

output_df.show(false)
// OUTPUT:
//+---+------------+---------------------------+
//|id |fields      |json_field                 |
//+---+------------+---------------------------+
//|1  |[f1, f2, f3]|{f1 -> 3, f2 -> 2, f3 -> 0}|
//|2  |[f2, f4]    |{f2 -> 4, f4 -> 5}         |
//|3  |[f1]        |{f1 -> 7}                  |
//+---+------------+---------------------------+
```

In DataFrame API, the same code can be:

```py
# Input data
data = [(1, "f1, f2, f3", 3, 2, 0, 2),
        (2, "f2, f4", 2, 4, 2, 5),
        (3, "f1", 7, 6, 4, 6)]
input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "fields", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"])

input_df.show(input_df.count(), False)

# Explode the 'fields' column into multiple rows
exploded_df = input_df.select("id", explode(split(input_df.fields, ", ")).alias("field"), "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")

# Create the 'json_field' column using the 'field' column and the 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4' columns with map_from_entries
output_df = (exploded_df.groupBy("id", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")
             .agg(collect_list("field").alias("fields"),
                  map_from_entries(collect_list(struct("field",
                                                       when(exploded_df.field == "f1", exploded_df.f1)
                                                       .when(exploded_df.field == "f2", exploded_df.f2)
                                                       .when(exploded_df.field == "f3", exploded_df.f3)
                                                       .when(exploded_df.field == "f4", exploded_df.f4)
                                                       )
                                                )
                                   ).alias("json_field")
                  )
             .orderBy("id")
             .select("id", "fields", "json_field"))

output_df.show(output_df.count(), truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The real situation is fields set is large (few hundreds), but each row might only need much smaller part of it, so grouping by all fields or conditionally check them might be very heavy.

I ended up with this hack:
1. First create a big json field with all fields, for each row.
2. Then use a UDF to filter those unneeded fields. The UDF takes fields, and full_json_field as input. 
3. Finally write the filtered JSON to new field.

Comment: You can check my below solution.. you don't need `udf` for this.